# Entry is no longer in view

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

In one of my xpages applications the following bug

[image]

was reported to me by a customer.

It is very confusing, because this issue should be fixed years ago:

> In Notes/Domino releases prior to 6.0, the error **"Entry is no longer
>   in view: "** would occur when accessing a property or method
>   of the NotesViewEntry class. This occurred in cases where the entry
>   was derived from a NotesViewEntryCollection based on the
>   GetAllEntriesByKey method (of the NotesView class), and when the
>   relative view had a column where the following property was
>   enabled"Show multiple values as separate entries" (found in the Column
>   Properties dialog box --> Sort Panel [second from left]). This issue
>   was resolved in Notes/Domino release 6.0 by a fix based on SPR#
>   CSMH483KAX.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21264910

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Did you set `view.AutoUpdate = false`?

Comment: @KnutHerrmann No I haven't set `autoUpdate=false` but I haven't any troubles up to now. Definitely no problems with domino server 8.5.3. I guess the troubles come with domino 9.0.1 probably with FP8.

Comment: @KnutHerrmann: Now i have testet setting `autoupdate=false` but the error isn't gone

Comment: Did you set it in your Java bean with `view.setAutoUpdate(false)` ?

Comment: Yes I set it in my java bean class

Comment: just a quick "confirmation": this still seems to be an issue; we're seeing this *occasionally* at a customer's site running 10.0.1FP3; the code in question is a LotusScript scheduled (daily) agent using exactly the methods described here. *occasionally* means that the agent ran into this issue 4 times in the course of the last 6 months. Not really much, but as this is a very critical part of a workflow it's still considered as "severe". I'm now trying to switch to using DocumentCollection and looping Docs instead of ViewEntries.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error "Entry is no longer in view:" in a java agent when running on server.
Each time, the error fired on the same document.
I didn't get this error if I run agent from my notes client.

I solve this problem by replacing ViewEntryCollection by ViewNavigator.